# Some images aren't loading when props are changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have problem when props changed but images in the child components are not shown unless the page refreshed manually  . There is no 404 error for images and when I inspect image element , surprisingly I see the correct image link but the image is broken .

[This is how the image is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPOzi.jpg%60)

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          screenshot : '',
          Mobilescreenshot : '',
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        var testId = this.props.location.query.id;
        this.setState({ url: '', isLoading: true, loadingModal: true, submitBTN: false });
        this.props.getOldReport(testId);
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.oldReport && this.state.isLoading) {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false,report_id : 
newProps.oldReport.report_id,
            screenshot : newProps.oldReport.screenshot
           })
        }
      }
```

---

- getOldReport(testId) method in componentDidMount returns screenshot image
- new screenshot image path stores in state through componentWillReceiveProps

this image path is passed into child component :

```
  <ReportTable
            first_paint_time={first_paint_time}
            overall_score={overall_score}
            page_speed_warning={page_speed_warning}
            yslow_warning={yslow_warning}
            page_load_time={page_load_time}
            page_bytes={page_bytes}
            screenshot = {"/images/screenshots/" + this.state.screenshot}
            report_id = { this.state.report_id}
          />
```

-----------Here is my child component for rendering the screenshot image

```
   const REPORT_SCREENSHOT = ({ 
     Mobilescreenshot,screenshot,first_paint_time,report_id }) => {
     console.log('SCREENSHOT  FROM INNER',screenshot);
     return (
    <div>
       <div style={{ marginBottom: '1.2rem' }} className='screenshot-macbook'>
         <img src={screenshot}/>
            <strong> 
               <p style={{ marginTop: '1.2rem' }} className="center">First render at :
                  {(first_paint_time / 1000).toFixed(2)}s</p>
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>

  );
}
```

-----I have access to screenshot path inside the above(child) component correctly . but the image is not shown when data fetching is finished . All other data are fetching and displaying correctly except screenshot image .

Answer (score 1):

You need require it in JSX.

`` <img src={require(`${screenshot}`)}/> ``